# Actionscript 3: Buttons always on top?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, movieclip

I'm working on a little game. So I need 4 layers in my main-timeline. In the bottom layer is a movieclip with some buttons in them. In the two layers above there are also movieclips for effects and actions and the layer on the top is for actionscript. The sequence for the layers is intended.

And when I test it I can't click on any buttons, because for sure there are movieclips above them. Is there a possibility in actionscript to say, that all buttons are always on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also make a call to addChild each time a new DisplayObject / DisplayObjectContainer is added over one of your buttons...

If your buttons are stored in a Vector as this:

```
var buttons:Vector.<SimpleButton> = new Vector.<SimpleButton>();
```

and you've a function like setButtonsOnTop

```
function setButtonsOnTop():void{
    for(var i:uint=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
        addChild(buttons[i]);
    }
}
```

Call the function when something is added over the buttons.

```
setButtonsOnTop();
```

So the buttons are always above the other DisplayObjects...

To remove the buttons you may do this by adding a "removeButtons" method:

```
function removeButtons():void{
    for(var i:uint=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
        removeChild(buttons[i]);
    }
}
```

So in this way you don't have to care about the index value.

Comment: You can also call the setButtonsOnTop() method when an event.ADDED is triggered...

Comment: Sounds great. Thank you, tatactic, I'll try to work with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the z-index by setting parent.setChildIndex(childObject, i). Set a very high index to ensure that its always on top

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/all-index-Z.html

Comment: Thank you! I will try to change the z-index.

Comment: Beware though!   Once you manipulate the parentage of an object originating on a timeline (setChildIndex/AddChild/AddChildAt), that object will no longer be affected by the timeline.  It will stay on the screen until either it's parent timeline is removed, or you explicitly remove it with `removeChild`.  Keyframes will not remove it.

Comment: Why do you want to change the z-index?
By reusing addChild method you don't have to care about the index?
You do not even to test the numChildren property.